# Adobe AIR Android: SWF is reloaded when app is reactivated after being idle

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash

I'm porting my AIR game to Android.

When the app is deactivated (loses fucus, but it's still running in the background), for example by pressing the *Home* key, and then user taps the app's icon to bring it into focus again, the runtime re-loads the SWF and there's two instances of the same SWF running on top of each other.

As far as I can tell, the runtime itself is not reloaded, only the SWF.

When I manually kill the process, and re-launch the app, all is fine. The whole thing happens only if the app remains in memory and is re-activated after being idle.

Is this a bug, or am I missing some property that needs to be set?

The runtime version is 17.

Thanks.

Comment: definitely not a bug, it's your code logic and code handling.

Comment: What Android version and AIR SDK? How did you determine that a second SWF was being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm. Turns out it was a stray **InvokeEvent** left over from the PC version. So @Aaron, you were right to assume I haven't researched this enough on my own. @BotMaster was also right :)

Thanks for pushing me in the right direction though. And sorry.